# Search text as keyword in array of object using Parse Platform or MongoDB aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform

I have some data like this in my Class Object or my Collection.

```
{
    "_id": "WI9jBNC13S",
    "metadataMedia": [{
        "media_id": "4329061",
        "text": "Happy Birthday Mrs. @nurhida.amin"
    }, {
        "media_id": "4329062",
        "text": "Please stay at home, keep healthy",
    }, {
        "media_id": "4329063",
        "text": "Good morning sedulur \nSelamat hari Sabtuuuu",
    }],
    "username": "pblp",
    "isMember": false,
    "_session_token": "r:2b47ec8c482d7043437"
}
```

I am trying to get some data (big data expected) from my MongoDB using Parse Platform.

I want to build **search feature** (like search engine) to get data from "**metadataMedia[].text**" attribute.

I have two options, using [Parse.Query.fullText()](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.13.0/Parse.Query.html#fullText) and [MongoDB Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/). I have no idea how to use one of them in array of object.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: I believe that you can use Parse.Query.fullText() in the array field as you would use in a text field but I highly recommend you to transform this array into a new class or a relation.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice. I use `unwind` to solve the problem.